# Peer to peer lending in Canada?

Tags: canada, peer-to-peer-lending

Is there a service similar to Lending Club in Canada or is it possible to use Lending Club without having a U.S. bank account?

Edit : If you have an answer that might help with opening a U.S. account and accessing a U.S. peer-to-peer lending website with it, I would consider this also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no, [P2P Capital Markets](http://www.p2pcapitalmarkets.com/) is similar concept but is more geared towards business loans.

[Community Lend](http://www.communitylend.com/public/index) used to offer this service but has stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although it's a bit frustrating to see that there doesn't seem to be any P2P in Canada for people with a smaller amount of money to invest (5~20k)

Comment: @StevenGilligan agreed, but hey there's an idea :). However it might have something to do with the banking laws perhaps.